# difference between login.events.pre and login.events.post

Tags: liferay-6

What is the difference between these two Startup Events

login.events.pre and login.events.post

Because when i developed a Liferay  6 Hookin and configured portal.properties files with these two .

Both of them has been called , only after clicking on Submit button on Default Liferay Login .

```
login.events.pre=com.sample.hook.LoginAction
login.events.post=com.sample.hook.LoginAction2
```

COuld this login.events.pre and login.events.post can be thought as Filters in Servlets ??

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Mark, I just answered in hurry!

Both of these events will be fired after successful login only.

login.events.pre generally performs basic preparations for user, e.g. populating ServicePreAction object.

login.events.post is after activity, where you set things in session or set your landing pages.

Comment: Nope, this is definitely not a correct answer, the answer from @Mark is closer to the actual reality...

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not a Filters. This actions will be call from MainServlet. For details see Liferay sources http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.0/javadocs/src-html/com/liferay/portal/servlet/MainServlet.html from line 988.

Comment: To be more accurate, MainServlet does the "login stuff" right at the first request made **after a successful login** (login sends a redirect to the client). Moreover, you can see in the `loginUser()` method that both "pre actions" and "post actions" are executed not quite far from each other. Therefore it is not quite clear why someone would need to really implement a "pre action" instead of a "post action"... This is just one of the "brain-teasers" which one can come along when trying to comprehend Liferay and its poorly documented API...